# Opencv DMatch distance out of range

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, range, out

I'm using FlannBasedMatcher according to a http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography . I'm getting error "vector subscript  out of range" everytime it run this line " double dist = matches[i].distance; " Any one can help out? I been stuck here for quite some time..

```
int minHessian = 400;

  SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

  detector.detect( img_object, keypoints_object );
  detector.detect( img_scene, keypoints_scene );

  //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
  SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

  Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

  extractor.compute( img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
  extractor.compute( img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

  //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
  FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
  std::vector< DMatch > matches;
  matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

  double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

  //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
  for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
  { double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
  }

  printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
  printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't get enough features from your images? Check keypoint's size.

Comment: the matcher doesnt seem to find and matches eventhough  both images are the same. the matches remains empty.

Comment: So "calculation of max and min distances between keypoints"  meaningless check lenght of matches  before them

Comment: What do you mean by that? i print out matches[0].distances, it still stated overrun. Is seems like there is nothing in matches...

Comment: but if i compare both same images, it should have 100% feature matches right?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this:

```
vector< vector<DMatch> > matches;
```

It's a vector of vector of DMatch!

Comment: Then, the  FlannBasedMatcher::match  will state there is no instance matching the argument list

Comment: That's weird... if you take a look at the file matchers.cpp:169 in the stitching module, that's exactly what they've done!

Answer (score 0):

In case you never solved this, make sure you are using the right kind of vectors the first one should be an `std::vector` whereas the second one is a `cv::vector`. So if you are not using any namespaces it should look like this:

`std::vector<cv::vector<cv::DMatch>> matches;`